# When run executable jar file i have and SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DENTAL

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I am working on a project, my project should be connected with `Database`, When I run it on `NetBeans` it works perfectly, But when I am try to run the executable jar file i have an error like this,

`"No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DENTAL"`

please note that I added the `mysql-connecter.jar` to libraries.

Thank you

Comment: Where you added? Lib folder?

Comment: in Libraries, i would like to mention that file "lib"  wasn't exist.. i created it manually

Comment: Are you exporting jar file with netbeans

Comment: Try with java –classpath /lib/* -jar App.jar

Comment: yes, doing Clean & Build

Comment: Maven based project?

Comment: how can i do this: classpath /lib/* -jar App.jar

Comment: Yes maven based

Comment: From commandline

Comment: i tried , doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the following to generate jar file:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>edu.learn.App</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>make-runnable-jar</id> 
      <phase>package</phase> 
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

then run mvn clean package